# Spring Framework: mvc:resources does not work

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

In my Spring Web Application project I've already configured an `mvc:resources` tag in order to exclude CSS, JS, images ... from DispatcherServlet mapping

Now I need to exclude also a foobar.txt and is placed under `/webapp` directory like the other static resources but ... It doesn't work.

Here my code snippet

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/assets/**" location="/assets/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/foobar.txt" location="/foobar.txt" />
```

my folder structure is:

```
   /webapp
    /webapp/assets
    /webapp/foobar.txt
    /webapp/...
```

It's seems like the the first mvc:resources tag (assets) works but the second one (version.txt) doesn't.

I get a 404 page.

These are the difference in console log.

```
2018-07-12 13:58:25,093 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-6] (DispatcherServlet.java:845) - DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher' processing GET request for [/mscbackend/foobar.txt]
2018-07-12 13:58:25,093 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-6] (AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:297) - Looking up handler method for path /foobar.txt
2018-07-12 13:58:25,096 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-6] (AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:305) - Did not find handler method for [/foobar.txt]
2018-07-12 13:58:25,097 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-6] (AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.java:123) - Mapping [/foobar.txt] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [ResourceHttpRequestHandler [locations=[ServletContext resource [/foobar.txt]], resolvers=[org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver@66894a78]]] and 1 interceptor

2018-07-12 14:08:27,165 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-7] (DispatcherServlet.java:845) - DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher' processing GET request for [/mscbackend/assets/css/style.css]
2018-07-12 14:08:27,165 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-7] (AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:297) - Looking up handler method for path /assets/css/style.css
2018-07-12 14:08:27,169 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-7] (AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:305) - Did not find handler method for [/assets/css/style.css]
2018-07-12 14:08:27,169 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-7] (AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.java:168) - Matching patterns for request [/assets/css/style.css] are [/assets/**]
```

The weird thing is that in another similar project same configuration works without problems.

Thanks in advance for your support.

Answer (score 0):

Try below configuration.

```
<mvc:resources location="/", mapping="/resources/**"/>
```

OR if you want to give classpath for a particular location use below.

```
<mvc:resources location="/, classpath:/META-INF/web-resources/" mapping="/resources/**"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this configuration.

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

I don't why, but sometimes it works. you can give a try.